# Type check object properties with square brackets

Tags: typescript

I have an interface like this :

```
interface Iobject {
"foo foo":string,
"bar bar":string
}
```

Then I define an function like this :

```
function example(exampleObject:Iobject){
  console.log(exampleObject['wrong wrong'])
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way for typescript to detect that there is no key "wrong wrong" and to give my an error when I try to access such a property. I am asking because I have an object with only keys with space inside so I can only access properties with squared brackets and I would like to get a type check.

Thank you

Comment: It should be giving you this error: _"Property 'wrong wrong' does not exist on type 'Iobject'.(7053)"_ [See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIHsBGArCCzIDeAUAEQzrrIXqkBcAzmFKAOYA0ZmcUy3U9JixCtiAX2LEYAVxD5g6EMggAPOAFsADgBsIAClUadEAPI48YOhnP4AlCWTIEihul0A6belYG1W3Wa4+ADaAOQA7lCKrMiR0aEAurbiQA) Are you using the latest version of typescript?

Comment: Thank you. Ok so now that I put `"noImplicitAny": true,` it checks the type. However, my whole projet has now many errors. Is there anyway to put noImplicitAny only in some parts of a projet?

Comment: No, I don't believe you can turn that on per file. You really _should_ turn that on for the codebase though, and then fix all the issues it flags.